# How to do request mapping with form action?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to map a form action with controller class but the mapping doesn't found for the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a quite general question. In general, you have a controller class (which is mapped in your configuration file) which listens for URLs. For example

```
@Controller
public class CommonController {

@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult results) {
    return "index";
}

}
```

In the page containing the form, you simply set your form action as `/index`. For example, if you use Thymeleaf

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/index.html}" th:object="${user}">
...
</form>
```

For more information, you could read [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/).

Answer (score 2):

Steps not in depth but understandable.

Create a Bean named as User like

```
package com.bean;

public class User 
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    getters and setters
}
```

Create html page for login like

```
 <form action="processform" method="post">
         firstname <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" name="firstName"/>  
         Oracle Password:<input type="text" placeholder="lastname" name="lastName"/>  
         <br/>
         <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

then write a controller to process form 
like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/processform")

    public ModelAndView processAdmissionForm( @ModelAttribute("user1") User user1)  
{
}
```